# Send to server the new this.state

Tags: reactjs

**Env.**
    - Backend Framework Flask
    - Frontend Framwork Reacjs

I'm trying to send to the server a value of the year, that the user selects in a dropdown menu. At the same time I'm changing the state to that same value. But from what I can see, I only can send the new value to the server after it renders. How can I do that.
This is my code:

```js
import React from "react"
import Years from "./Years"

require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

class HeaderYear extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {date: this.props.year}
    this.dropdownFunction = this.dropdownFunction.bind(this)
    this.sendStateToServer = this.sendStateToServer.bind(this)
    this.changeYear = this.changeYear.bind(this)
  }

  dropdownFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myDropdownYear").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  sendStateToServer() {
    // Set the global variable
    let statenow = this.props.year
    var payload = {
      year: statenow
    }
    console.log('payload is ' + JSON.stringify(statenow));
    fetch('/year',
    {
      /* Options are only needed in POST methods */
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    }
    ).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        response.json().then(data => {
          console.log(data);;
        })
    })
  }

  changeYear(year) {
    this.setState({date: year})
    console.log(this.state.date);
    this.sendStateToServer()
  }

  render () {
    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <button onClick={this.dropdownFunction} className="dropbtn">{this.state.date}</button>
        <ul id="myDropdownYear" className="dropdown-content">
          {this.props.years.map(year => {
            return <Years key={year} id={year} onClick={this.changeYear} year={year}/>
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )

  }
}

export default HeaderYear
```

The Year Component:

```js
import React from "react"

class Years extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.changeYear = this.changeYear.bind(this)
  }

  changeYear() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.id)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.changeYear}>{this.props.year}</li>
    )
  }
}

export default Years
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the sendStateToServer() function inside the callback function of the setState() function.

```js
this.setState({date: year}, ()=>{
  sendStateToServer();
})
```

What the callback function does is to wait for the state to be changed and then it fires the actions inside it.

Comment: I did not helped. I keeps sending the previous state at each change.

Comment: I got it. I added the new state to the callback function parameter, like so: this.setState({date: year}, ()=>{
  sendStateToServer(this.state.date);
}). And updated the sendStateToServer, and it now works. Thanks